# Can I build a compiler plugin with a post processor to generate code from previous collected derived structs?

Tags: macros, rust, rust-compiler-plugin

As far as I know current usage for compiler plugin is to define the attribute for compiler to recognize and then the compiler will invoke the code defined and registered in the plugin.

I am thinking if it is possible to build a compiler plugin that have a post processor. I can some how first register the structs encountered by `proc_macro_derive` in a data structure within the plugin, then the post processor can generate code according to the plugin data structure populated before.

My intention is to generate a symbol table form derived structs, so I can do some experiment for dynamic typing in rust. I am not sure if it is possible to achieved in compile time without manually register them one by one in runtime.